# Cannot find 'entity' in scope SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to display the detail of an item from a list on to a sheet. I'm getting this error `Cannot find 'entity' in scope` even though it's declared in the detail item struct.

This error doesn't appear if the sheet is inside of the list BUT this causes only the first item detail to be shown even if you select any of the other items below the first.

This is a macOS app.

```
                @StateObject var vm = CoreDataViewModel()

                  List {
                    ForEach(vm.savedEntites) { entity in
                        Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                        HStack {
                        Button(action: {vm.deleteMemory(entity: entity)}) {
                                       Label("Delete",systemImage: "trash")
       
                                     }.foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                     
                            Button(action: {showingDetailScreen.toggle()}) {
                            Label("Details", systemImage: "pencil")
                                     }.foregroundColor(Color(.red))                       
                        }                          
                    }// list ends here                
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetailScreen) {
                        DetailItemView(entity: entity,isVisible: self.$showingDetailScreen)
                           }
                }
```

Detail Item View Struct

```
struct DetailItemView: View  {
        var entity: MemoryEntity
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        @Binding var isVisible: Bool
        
 
        var body: some View {
            Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
            HStack {
            Button("Exit") {
                self.isVisible = false
                   }
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
            }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntites: [MemoryEntity] = []
    @Published var selectedEntity: String = ""
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MemoryContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print("Error loading CoreData. \(error)")
        }
        }
        FetchMemories()
    }
    
    func FetchMemories() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<MemoryEntity>(entityName: "MemoryEntity")
        do {
        savedEntites = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching \(error)")
        }
    }   
   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of entity is inside ForEach brackets,

```
ForEach(vm.savedEntites) { entity in
                                                                                
} //End scope entity var
```

If you want to show a present outside ForEach, as a suggestion you could declare in your viewModel a selectedEntity as @Published

```
List {
   ForEach(vm.savedEntites) { entity in
   Button(action: {
       vm.selectedEntity = entity
       showingDetailScreen.toggle()
   }) {
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetailScreen) {
   DetailItemView(entity: vm.selectedEntity,isVisible: self.$showingDetailScreen)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How should i declare "selectedEntity" in the view model? i've tried as a string and i'm getting .Cannot assign value of type 'MemoryEntity' to type 'String' error. I've updated the question with the model.

Comment: @Published var selectedEntity: MemoryEntity?